# Why does IE8 ignore a child element's margin?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

When I add a `margin` to `.child` in the following code IE8 ignores it. In modern browsers the same code is working as expected. What is causing this?

```html
<html lang=“de“ xml:lang=“de“ xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv=“Content-Type“ content=“text/html“; charset=“iso-8859-1“ />
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .parent {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 10px solid blue;
      position: relative;
    }
    .child {
      margin: 10px;
      border: 10px solid red;
      padding: 4px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="parent">
    <p class="child" style="width:80%; position:relative; left:10px; top:10px; background-color:yellow;">I'm the CHILD!
      <span id="textOutput"></span>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: IE8 is not a modern browser :)

Comment: Please include full code (including HTML). Not been able to reproduce this with the styles provided.

Comment: Okay! I updated my code! Please guys, Check it again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not supplied a `doctype` which means that IE8 does not know what rendering mode to use and is therefore defaulting to quirks mode. Quirks mode is essential an old, non-standard layout engine used back when the web was young:

> There are now three modes used by the layout engines in web browsers: quirks mode, almost standards mode, and full standards mode. In quirks mode, layout emulates nonstandard behavior in Navigator 4 and Internet Explorer 5. This is essential in order to support websites that were built before the widespread adoption of web standards. In full standards mode, the behavior is (hopefully) the behavior described by the HTML and CSS specifications. In almost standards mode, there are only a very small number of quirks implemented.

*Quirks Mode and Standards Mode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)*

Browsers handle a lack of `doctype` in different ways and you should always ensure that you specify one at the beginning of you HTML to ensure consistent rendering of your page. At time of writing I would recommend the HTML5 `doctype` as it is short, clear and supported as far back as IE6.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .parent {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 10px solid blue;
      position: relative;
    }
    .child {
      margin: 10px;
      border: 10px solid red;
      padding: 4px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <p class="child" style="width:80%; position:relative; left:10px; top:10px; background-color:yellow;">I'm the CHILD!
      <span id="textOutput"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*It should also be noted that you need to use normal quotation marks not curly quotes for your attribute values and need a closing `html` tag.*